# Functionality is working "fine" or "as expected"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Here the functionality is related with web Site responses.

Now I'm looking for a sentence which would be preferable when,

> ABC functionality was not working before, *(Explanation of some
>   work has been done to fix the functionality)* and now is working
>   **fine** or **as expected**?.

I studied this thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/this-works-fine-is-this-correct).
In my case though, ABC was not working, it is fixed and now it is working. Should I use **fine** here? Or something else you could suggest?

Comment: "As expected" is more precise than "fine".  Also, when referring to a specific unit or part of a piece of software, "feature" or "function" might be less clunky than "functionality".  For example: *The "submit feedback" feature is now working as expected.*

Comment: Ya. Had no idea about _functionality_  because we kinda mention the feature itself. So thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Agree with @augurar. For software world, *fine* sounds a bit informal and perhaps vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer "**...now is working as intended.**"

or "**...now is working as designed.**"

The potential problem with **as expected** is that someone might **expect** it to fail.

**EDIT:**

To address your comment, I think that "**as intended**" and "**as designed**" are interchangeable in this context.  However, you might use both words just to avoid the repetition of ***designed***.

***This menu was designed to do XYZ.  For a time it was not fully functional.  After the code was improved, the menu is now working as intended.***

Comment: +1. "works as designed" is the standard phrase. Popular bug management tools have this option defined explicitly to close or defer tickets.

Comment: OK. Now _now is working as intended_ seems precise. 
Though I'm confused about _now is working as designed_. 
Designed always seems like related to visual-related stuff or something which is feature itself _this menu is designed to do XYZ_.
That might look in the sentence like _this menu was designed to this XYZ... and now is working as designed_ .
English is not my native language. Does this statement sounds correct?

Comment: @Drag0nKn1ght:  See my edited answer.

Comment: +1 for "... as intended". The others don't sound as good. If you want to use *design*, I'd prefer "... [the behaviour] now corresponds to the design". The "... works as designed" version works when talking about the code implementing the architecture, but is a tautology at the level of the programmer. There's also the option to simply truncate it to "... is now working (correctly)."

Answer (score 0):

I would like either

> The functionality is now as expected.

or

> The web site is now woking as expected.

but not

> The functionality is now working as expected.